# When sliding up a collapsing toolbar can I have a circular image view in the left corner of toolbar?

Tags: android

I'm using a collapsing toolbar which on sliding up gives a toolbar. Can I get a circular image view in the left corner of the toolbar when sliding up the collapsing toolbar?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I got it how to set that.